# Showing $||f - S_{n}(f)||_{2}^{2}$ $=$ $||f||_{2}^{2}$ $-$ $||S_{n}(f)||_{2}^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am learning about Fourier Series in Carother's Real Analysis. 
We have just learned the Fourier Partial Sum $S_{n}(f)$ is the closest function to $f$ in the set of trigonometric polynomials with at most degree n, $T_{n}$, with respect to the $L_{2}$ norm. i.e 
\begin{align}
\underset{T \in T_{n}}{\inf}||f-T|| =||f-S_n(f)||
\end{align}

The author then writes the following:
\begin{align}
||f - S_{n}||^{2} &= ||f||^{2} - ||S_{n}(f)||^{2}\\
    &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^{2}(x)dx - \frac{\alpha_{0}^{2}}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{k}^{2}+\beta_{k}^{2}
\end{align}

**I don't understand how the author gets this result.**

I have shown $||S_{n}(f)||^{2} = \frac{\alpha_{0}^{2}}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{k}^{2}+\beta_{k}^{2}$, then have tried multiplying out $||f- S_{n}(f)||^{2} = ||f||^{2} - 2||fS_{n}(f)||+ ||S_{n}(f)||^2$  and simplifying it with what I have shown. However, no luck. If anyone can point me into the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This says $\left\|f-S_n(f)\right\|^2 + \left\|S_n(f)\right\|^2 = \left\|f\right\|^2$. Can you explain why $f-S_n(f)$ is **orthogonal** to $S_n(f)$, and recall/show that $\left\| g+h\right\|^2 =\left\|g\right\|^2 + \left\|h\right\|^2$ if $g$ and $h$ are orthogonal?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Yes, is there an issue?

Comment: It is a potential clue when written like that (based on orthogonality).

Comment: Fantastic, I will give this a try with your clue thank you.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I can explain why $f - S_{n}(f)$ is orthogonal to $S_{n}(f)$ however, I cannot show it rigorously. I have tried the following: $\langle f - S_{n}(f), S_{n}(f)\rangle = \langle f,S_{n}(f) \rangle - \langle S_{n}(f),S_{n}(f)\rangle = $$\frac{\alpha_{0}a_{0}}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\alpha_{k}a_{k} + \beta_{k}b_{k})$ $-$ $\frac{a_{0}^{2}}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_{k}^{2} + b_{k}^{2})$. However, I cannot see how this would equal $0$. In other words, I cannot see why $\langle f,S_{n}(f) \rangle = \langle S_{n}(f),S_{n}(f) \rangle $. Thanks.